# Security: deploying the API - PHP & Linux using ssh

Tags: php, security, api, ssh

I am planning on deploying a REST API developed using PHP and running on a Centos Linux system. The application evolved, and the API now provides access to potentially sensitive data. I do not want to go with a complicated solution like oAuth, and was wondering if there's a simpler solution involving ssh certificates. The clients accessing this API include standard desktops, as well as iPhone and Android devices. I realize that this is not exactly a programming question, but in a way it is, because it's about securely accessing the code I'm developing.

Comment: How will https protect me? wouldn't anyone be able to call the API using https?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably meant client SSL certificates. It will work, your only potential future trouble is managing the certificates - issuing, revoking, distributing and so on. Obviously this will only be the case if the user base is large or experiences a lot of change. OAuth does not have this problem.

Check any Google results on how to set this up, for example http://www.impetus.us/~rjmooney/projects/misc/clientcertauth.html looks good.